# How to get attribute column value?

Tags: javascript, html

I have widgets, these are defined as a `DockPanel`. I want the user to drag and drop to save the last zone location in the layout through database support.

In JavaScript I call my webmethod and I want to attach zone's `name` and `widgetname` but I did not send widgetname. I want to reach `widgetname`'s value by using some JavaScript code. I reach the `Attributes` column name (I can see `id` in the inspect window), but I want to reach the attributes column name `value`. How can I fix this?

```
var getID = document.getElementById('Panel').getAttributeNames()[1];  
//This shows me "id" in inspect windows.
```

I want to reach the `value`. Even though I tried to write `document.getElementById('Panel').getAttributeNames()[1].value()` but I did not see the value writing here.

Comment: Is: `var attributeValue = document.getElementById("Panel").getAttribute("Id");` what you are looking for? Sounds like your code is doing what you're asking it to do "**getAttributeNames**"

Comment: Yeah so so,My code works a little,Because I want to define My widgetpanel's widget's panel names.So How can I reach them?

Comment: Well, you could just add a class name like `class="panels"` and then `var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('panels');` and then for loop those. if you want to set attrbute value to those you can use `element.setAttribute("nameOfAttribute", "AttributeValueYouWantToSet");`

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but here I have also problems.I use that you said similar     elements = document.getElementsByClassName('WidgetPanelID');
             var i;
                function fff() {
                    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                       var vary= elements.getAttribute("id");
                        console.log(vary);
                    }
                }
         But I do not reach even though my widget class is declared.Is there a way to fix?Also I do not want to set anything.I want to get the attributes value in this path

Comment: Thanks guys.I solved the problem I have to call e.panel.GlobalName at the after dock operation.

Answer (score 0):

getAttribute() is a function that returns the value of the attribute specified. More info about this function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

You can use:

**var getID = document.getElementById('Panel').getAttribute("id")**

Pay attention to use lowercase for the attribute "id".

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I tried these I have widget panel and my widgets are stored in this panel.but my widgets declared as dockpanel also.So I want to reach my widgets dockpanel like 'GooglePanel','TradingPanel'... But only here,I reach the general panel which is 'WidgetPanel' how canI get them.